# Wordpress rss notification

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, notifications

We have a self hosted wordpress.org site that has blog.
I have read that when you publish and unpublish then publish the same post it will notify your subscribers twice for the same post.  We are changing the look and feel of our blog and want to unpublish some of the post then republish them without notifying the subscribers.  Is there a function I can add to my functions file that would check to see if there is a post date.  Here would be a sudo code idea.

if (post->date < current date){
Then don't notify subscribers
}else {
run notification as normal
}

I currently don't have a plugin managing my rss2 feed subscription button just the wordpress function.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publishing your post from an unpublished state shouldn't push to the RSS unless you changed the date.

Comment: Many blogs had different things to say about this.  All the testing I did on my development site was proving what you said was true.  Thanks

Comment: No problem @gtershel! I wonder why other people had inconsistent results. That's never good!